# Setting Socket Timeout?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

Using sockets, I am not sure how to set the timeout?

thanks

```
int sock, connected, bytes_recieved;
char send_data [128] , recv_data[128];       
SOCKADDR_IN server_addr,client_addr;    
int sin_size;
int j = 0;

::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         
server_addr.sin_port = htons(4000);     
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
::listen(sock, 5);
::fflush(stdout);

while(1)
{  
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    connected = ::accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);

    while (1)
    {
        j++;

        ::send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);  

        //dealing with lost communication ? 
        //and reastablishing communication
        //set timeout and reset on timeout error    
    }
}
::closesocket(sock);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A socket is in blocking mode by default.  If you switch it to non-blocking mode using `ioctlsocket(FIONBIO)`, you can use `select()` to manage timeouts:

```
SOCKET sock, connected;
int bytes_recieved;  
char send_data [128] , recv_data[128];         
SOCKADDR_IN server_addr,client_addr;      
int sin_size;  
int j = 0, ret;  
fd_set fd;
timeval tv;

sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;           
server_addr.sin_port = htons(4000);       
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   

::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));  
::listen(sock, 1);  
::fflush(stdout);  

u_long nbio = 1;
::ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nbio);

while(1) 
{   
    FD_ZERO(&fd);
    FD_SET(sock, &fd);

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    if (select(0, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
    {
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); 
        connected = ::accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size); 

        nbio = 1;
        ::ioctlsocket(connected, FIONBIO, &nbio);

        while (1) 
        { 
            j++; 

            if (::send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0) < 0)
            {
                //dealing with lost communication ?  
                //and reastablishing communication 
                //set timeout and reset on timeout error     

                if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    FD_ZERO(&fd);
                    FD_SET(connected, &fd);

                    tv.tv_sec = 5;
                    tv.tv_usec = 0;

                    if (select(0, NULL, &fd, NULL, &tv) > 0)
                        continue;
                }

                break;
            }
        } 

        closesocket(connected);
    } 
}
```

Comment: question:  select(0, NULL, &set, NULL, &tv) where "set" is an "int" but for "fd_set" it wants... SOCKET  fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];   /* an array of SOCKETs */ I am not using that type so how do I get around this?  thx

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`setsockopt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the `SO_SNDTIMEO` and/or `SO_RCVTIMEO` options.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
fd_set fd;
timeval tv;
FD_ZERO(&fd);
FD_SET(sock, &fd);
tv.tv_sec = time_out(second);
tv.tv_usec = 0;
```

to set timeout for sending,receiving data.