# linux socket reception leaving

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am receiving data using recvfrom function like:

```
bytes = recvfrom(my_socket, message, 1522, 0, NULL, 0);
```

Normally recvfrom function is always waiting for receiving data. I want it to let it leave after some time past no matter whether there is data or not. However I could not manage it to leave from that state in case there is not any data (blocking). Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: To clarify, you want to listen for a set time window, then close the socket whether data is received or not?

Comment: Yes in any case I want to close it after certain time is passed.

Comment: in non-blocking mode you can manage timeouts, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.  Here is a link anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847441/setting-socket-timeout also I don't know if that information applies only to Visual C++

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the function [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). What select is?

Select is a function that look after a pool of filedescriptor. When some descriptor is moving (doing an action), select will tell you. Then you can perform an action.

If you have any question, you are welcome :)

Comment: Or better still, epoll, which does the same thing, but better, and with a much cleaner API that is easier to use correctly. :)

Comment: Yeah :D I am maybe a little hipster. Vote up for your comment!