# Can't get return value after socket accept()

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I have a Client/Server program. The client runs fine. But when client gets a 10060 error, the server seems stucking at accept() and can't get return value.     How can I fix this? I need accept() to return an error so that server can go on to do other stuff.

Client code:

```
SOCKET sock, sendrecv;  
sendrecv = myInitClientSocket(szIP, 6666);
if ( sendrecv ==0 ){  //socket 10060 error so that myInitClientSocket returns 0
    int err= WSAGetLastError();
    shutdown(sendrecv, 0x02);
    closesocket(sendrecv);
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
SOCKET sock, sendrecv;
struct sockaddr_in sock_addr,sendrecv_addr;
WSADATA data;
WORD p;
p=MAKEWORD(2,2);
int resStartup = WSAStartup(p,&data);
sock = WSASocket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int nREUSEADDR = 1;
setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char*)&nREUSEADDR,sizeof(int)); 

sock_addr.sin_family=PF_INET;
sock_addr.sin_port=htons(6666);         
sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
int resBind =   bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
int resListen =listen(sock, 5); 
int lun = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
sendrecv = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&sendrecv_addr,&lun);  //stucking here 
if(sendrecv == INVALID_SOCKET  )   
{
    //can't go in here
    return 5 ;
}
```

Comment: Error 10060 indicates that the attempt to connect to the server failed, e.g., because the network is down or because it was blocked by a firewall.  The server has no way of knowing that the client was trying to connect, so the accept() is still waiting for the connection.

Comment: `accept` returns once there's a connection, and your client is not connecting (because of some error that causes it to not connect). What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @HarryJohnston  In that case, I need a mechanism that handle this situation. For example, after 10min server will stop accepting, return a value and do other stuff.

Comment: @immibis   Well, I expect the server can stop waiting for connection and do other stuff.

Comment: Also, I don't actually see a question here.

Comment: @immibis  My question is, accept() can't return and server hangs in there. How to fix this?

Comment: @MinKim thats dependant on why your connection is failing, which we have no idea of. Maybe a firewall is blocking it, maybe the internet (or intranet) isn't stable. Maybe your server Has security settings prohibiting the client from connecting to it. There could be 10000 reasons for why this is failing and troubleshooting them is out of the scope of SO.

Comment: @MinKim Really broad question with lots of possible answers. For example, if you don't call `accept`, then it won't wait for a connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`accept` call can't return you a value because this call is supposed to block the execution of the process and wait for a client to arrive. If you do nothing and client doesn't appear, `accept` won't return forever.

What you need here is

1. Use `select` prior to `accept` to see if there is a pending client available.

or

2. Use `setsockopt` to set the `SO_SNDTIMEO` and/or `SO_RCVTIMEO` options to make `accept` exit after some time or even immediately.

Implementation details can be found here: [How to accept socket with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045064/how-to-accept-socket-with-timeout) and [Setting Socket Timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847441/setting-socket-timeout)

Comment: I use select() before accept(). It works perfect! Thank you!